# Adding a pixel border to an image in java

Tags: java

I am trying to create an image that adds a border to an existing image on Java by copying the pixels from their old locations to new coordinates. So far, this is what I have done:

```
 public static NewPic border(NewPic p, int borderWidth, Pixel borderColor) {
    int w = 2 * borderWidth;
    int h = 2 * borderWidth;


    Pixel[][] src = p.getBitmap();
    Pixel[][] tgt = new Pixel[w][h];

    for (int x = 0; x < w; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < h; y++) {
            if (x < borderWidth || x >= (w - borderWidth) ||
                    y < borderWidth)
                tgt[x][y] = borderColor;
            else
                tgt[x][y] = src[x - borderWidth][y - borderWidth]; 

        }
    }

return new NewPic(tgt);    

}
```

Not sure why this isn't passing my test case. Can anybody provide me with any guidance?

Thanks!

Comment: So what was wrong with the previous answer to this question?  What is `NewPic` and `Pixel`?  These aren't standard Java classes?  Where did they come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't w and h be the width and height of src *plus* twice the borderwidth? You're creating tgt just big enough to hold the border color.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html) and draw lines.